# Visual Studio generate DTMF tones in skype in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, skype

I am using Visual studio's to open Skype and place a call. I wish to have a ten digit touch pad. So i can press 1 in the program and it send the 1 DTMF tone through skype. Any help would be great! Also i am using visual basic as the language. I don't know where to start so i didn't post my code. I have the buttons  and it can call. butthat's about it,

Comment: Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour].  If you dont have any code, you are just asking us to do it for you.  Very unlikely to happen.  It also means that you havent done enough research if you have no idea.

Comment: i understand you wish you keep the website organized. but i'm asking for a single line of code. There is no need to include the code for a button press. I'm looking for a code along the lines of                                                  skype.tone(1) or skype.usnum(1) or skype.tone.dtmf(1)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    skype.Client.ButtonReleased("1")
End Sub
```